# When changing instance type of self - managed Eks cluster node from CloudFormation, what happens to the services and deployments on eks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

So, I want to change the instance type of node attached to eks via CloudFormation. My only trouble is I am not able to find what will happen to all the services and pods running on my eks cluster, if I change the node instance type. I checked the AWS documentation and googled the same as well, but not able to find any information regarding the same. A detailed answer will be appreciated, as I am new to AWS and Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

A change of the instance type of a managed node-group in EKS would imply a complete replacement of the node group, and so the running nodes will be destroyed and so the running services and deployments will be restarted again once a new matching node of the new node group is started.

Unfortunately, AWS currently does not implement full control of the autoscaling group via the EKS node group. For example, if you want to change the type of the instances in an autoscaling group, and you want to save the currently running node you would do it by the following steps:

- Detach the running nodes without starting new ones in the autoscaling group.
- Shut down the instances, change their type and start them again.
- Re-attach them to the autoscaling group.

But as I already mentioned, if you do so, the node-group will start complaining and will be failing, as it does not accept changes coming from the Autoscaling Group, but only changes going from it to the autoscaling group and not vice versa.

We hope in the future more control over the autoscaling group attached to a node group would be added to AWS.